# How to format DateTime to string with GMT offset

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a small c# windows form application that consume a web service from another appliction and submit records.

This web service need to receive a datetime value with the following format:

`"2016-10-10T23:00:00-03:00"`

Where the `-03:00`is the GMT (Argentina)

I have 2 date time pickers where i pick the date and time and later i concatenate the info in a string that have the required format.

So i need to send this value to the WebService in a Date format.
Then i tried the following:

```
String sFinalDate ="2016-10-10T23:00:00-03:00";
Date dFinalDate= new DateTime();
dFinalDate=Covert.ToDateTime(sFinalDate);
```

The issue here is that the `dFinalDate` save the following format:
`"10/06/2016 23:00:00"`

How can i convert my string to a Date field with the format that i need?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you interacting with the web service?  If you use a generated proxy the parameters should be `DateTime` values and you don't need to worry about the format.  Try just setting the parameter to `dFinalDate` and come back if that doesn't work.  The proxy will convert it to the right string format to generate the XML.

Comment: A `DateTime` value doesn't *have* a format. It's just a date and time. When you want the value as text again, format it how you want it *then*.

Answer (score 2):

You described a bastardized form of the `Round-trip Format Specifier`.

An example of the standard usage looks like this:

```
// this emits a string that looks like: 2016-06-13T15:30:55.2216814-04:00 
var dt = DateTime.Now.ToString("o");  // <-- round-trip format
```

Your requirement is to have the format without the milliseconds, so you would need to use a custom format specifier like this:

```
// this gives you a date string that looks like: 2016-06-13T15:30:55-04:00
var dt = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ssK");
```

More on the round-trip format:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx#Roundtrip

Comment: Sigh - I give the officially correct answer and someone -1's it. Very nice.